# Do any of these properties of unlabeled rooted trees have commonly understood names?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, trees

I've been trying to write up a proof recently which involves several properties of unlabeled rooted trees. Do any of these properties have commonly used names I am not aware of (so that I need not define them in my proof), or are any of the names I have chosen used for other properties of trees (so that I should choose a different name to avoid confusion)?

An exhaustive list of terms I'm using, to be on the safe side:

- Given an unlabeled rooted tree, I say that a node in the tree has **depth** equal to the distance between it and the root and the tree has **depth** equal to the maximum depth among all non-leaf roots.
- A node is **maximal** if its depth equals that of the tree and no other node at that depth has greater degree. The number of leaves adjacent to the maximal node in a tree (0 if no such node exists) is the **deepest degree** of the tree.
- The subtree descending from each child of the root is a **branch** of the tree, and a branch containing a maximal node of the tree is a **maximal branch**.
- Finally, a branch is **undecorated** if every leaf in the branch is at the same depth.